# C# column length of dataset created by Excel with ExcelDataReader is always -1

Tags: c#, datatable, dataset, cycle, exceldatareader

I import a file into a dataset with this method using the `ExcelDataReader` library

```
using ExcelDataReader;

public DataSet EstraiContenuto(IFormFile file)
{
        using (var inputStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            // read file to stream
            file.CopyTo(inputStream);
            //converto in dataset

            switch (file.ContentType)
            {
                case "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet":
                    {
                        using var reader = ExcelReaderFactory.CreateReader(inputStream);

                        return reader.AsDataSet(new ExcelDataSetConfiguration()
                        {
                            ConfigureDataTable = (_) => new ExcelDataTableConfiguration()
                            {
                                UseHeaderRow = true
                            }
                        });
                    }               
            }                   
        }       
    }
```

Then I need to work on it to get length of every column (I need to create a SQL statement to create a table and all columns will be of datatype `NVARCHAR`).

```
DataTable dataTable = dati.Tables[0];

foreach (DataColumn column in table.Columns)
{
    column.MaxLength;
}
```

but `MaxLength` is never populated.

is there a way to avoid having to manually iterate all rows?

Thanks

Comment: What do you want the `MaxLength` property to be set to?

Comment: max lenght of column column toString() content

Comment: You mean you want to find the longest string in each column? I imagine you'll just have to go through each cell to find the longest length.

Comment: i was looking for some integrated and optimized way to avoid doing it manually

Comment: I've been there. Depending on how critical this application is: It sounds a bit dirty, but just set the type to nvarchar(4000) And throw an Exception for invalid input. It is the maximum SQL server can handle efficiently without creating a blob in the background. So most likely there is no real world use case for supporting longer data.

Comment: was my first solution but i have to dynamically generate index on multiple columns and oralce set limit to index at around 26k char, so max 6 columns. i was attempting to reduce column with based on content to bypass that

Comment: ExcelDataReader dropped a new prerelease version yesterday with a TransformValue calllback option for AsDataSet. The callback is invoked for every value while building the DataSet and could be used to calculate a MaxLength per column. Personally I would not use AsDataSet if performance is important, just iterate the data manually using the reader object - like AsDataSet but without the extra pass.